# open access file from command line - cover all versions

Tags: ms-access, batch-processing

I have some trouble opening access file from command line.

start "FullPath\Database.mdb" - does nothing

start "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE14\MSACCESS.EXE" "FullPath\Database.mdb"
Opens the file normally

But different computers can have different versions of office, how can i cover all corners here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Access is installed, it usually ensures that the `msaccess` executable is available in the system path. Try it right now: hit <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, type `msaccess`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

So you can leave out the folder path in your command to start Access, and it should work on any computer where Access is properly installed.

Comment: so, like this?

start "%HOMEDRIVE%%sysPATH%\msacess.exe" "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\Database.accdb"

Comment: This is fine: `start msaccess c:\my\file.accdb`.